# T-SQL "not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, aggregate

I have a working query which will tell me the closest store location to every zipcode in the US, but when I try to have the Outer Query select the related zip-code of said store, it tells me that I have to add the ZipCode to an aggregate; however, if I do an order by Zip, then it doesn't show me all of the Cartesian product.  Any help is appreciated.

```
select
Sub1.Zip as Zip,
Sub1.Zip_ID as Zip_ID,
MIN(Sub1.Distance) as Distance from
    (
    SELECT 
    Z.Zip,
    Z.Zip_ID, 
       ((Sqrt(Square((Z.lat  - S.lat) *68.96799738887665) 
         + Square((Z.long - S.long)*54.69366983621222)))) Distance
    FROM   
    Tbl_Stores_Coordinates S
    CROSS JOIN Zip_Code_Coordinates Z
    )Sub1
group by Sub1.Zip_ID
```

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because you are `SELECT`ing `Zip` and `Zip_ID` but you are only `GROUP`ing by `Zip_ID`.

You have to `GROUP` by all the non-aggregated columns you `SELECT`, as so:

```
select
Sub1.Zip as Zip,
Sub1.Zip_ID as Zip_ID,
MIN(Sub1.Distance) as Distance
....
group by Sub1.Zip, Sub1.Zip_ID
```